# Why is money called "rhino"?

Tags: etymology, slang, money

I was going to the hole-in-the-wall to get some *rhino* the other day, when I started to wonder why cash is so-called.

I hit the books. Farmer & Henley gives no etymology. Partridge says

> Origin problematic; there is probably some allusion to the size of a rhinoceros or the price which almost any part of its corpse will fetch as an aphrodisiac.

This is supported by the related terms *rhino-fat*, *rhinoceral* and *rhinocerical*, all meaning 'rich'.

Green thinks

> ety. unk.; one suggestion, that it refers to the rhinoceros, then a fabulous creature 'worth its weight in gold', implies a certain lexicographical desperation

I had no luck with online sources either [(here)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rhino).

So, does anyone know why money is called *rhino*?

Comment: So, I've learnt something new today. Despite my addiction to English, I had never heard this term being used with reference to cash. Is it a term that people would recognize outside the UK? Can it be freely used (I suppose in a colloquial context)?

Comment: @Paola: I'm a native speaker from the US, and this word was new for me, too.

Comment: @Paola: I'm a native speaker from the UK, and this word was new for me, too.

Comment: [This book](http://books.google.fi/books?id=RfxcbpXhCZoC&pg=PA33&dq=rhino+slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M1PBT6OwFZP44QT0opjkCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rhino%20&f=true) is also doubtful of Partridge's etymology.

Comment: @Paola I'm also a native speaker from the UK, and have never heard this expression.

Comment: In the old song, "Man Who Broke the Bank at Monte Carlo," there is this: "...I've now got lots of money, I'm a gent. Yes, I now have lots of rhino, I'm a gent." You can listen to it on YouTube. It's a good old song.

Comment: I remember a 'clean' verse to the rugby song The Wild West Show that mentions the Rhinoceros as being the richest animal in the world because the first half of the name Rhino means money and the last is ceros (pronounce sore-ass) or piles, giving piles of money.

Comment: Several of the suggested derivations here seem to be based on Cockney rhyming slang, or something similar. That does tend to produce slang terms which are (deliberately) very hard for the uninitiated to understand.

Comment: As a US English speaker, hole-in-the-wall, without context, inevitably defaults to mean an obscure food joint.  So _“rhino”_ in the OP sentence gravitates heavily toward the literal – as in a _“rhino steak”_.  (In San Diego county hole-in-the-wall is a beach where high school kids go to drink and have sex – so on first blush it might mean … getting sex.)

Comment: Many seventeenth- and early eighteenth-century sources (including Jonathan Swift) refer to "ready rino," not "ready rhino," as the slang term for ready money—but since I don't know where _rino_ comes from either, that interesting fact doesn't really help me much.

Comment: The questioner means an ATM or cash dispenser. As a UK English speaker I know the term 'rhino' for money only as archaic slang.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably an unanswerable question, but an interesting suggestion is that the 'rhino' being alluded to is not the pachyderm, but the nose (as in rhinology or rhinoplasty), and 'rhino' as cash is linked to the earlier phrase 'paying through the nose'.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+through+the+nose

Answer (score 8):

The hilarous *A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue* (**[1785](http://books.google.com/books?id=zLAJs0_prpwC&pg=PT166&dq=%22rhinocerical%22)**)

has these interesting entries:

> **RHINO**, money, (*cant*)

> **RHINOCERICAL**, rich (*cant*); the cull is rhinocerical

So these expressions might have been somewhat current in the late 1700:s

Other expressions for being rich:

> **GINGERBREAD**:... also money; he has the gingerbread; he is rich

> **OAK** a rich man, a man of good substance and credit

Answer (score 6):

As you say, the origin is uncertain. The OED has mentioned the earliest instances of its usage, which are as follows:

> 1688  **Shadwell**, *Sqr. Alsatia I*:- "Thou shalt be rhinocerical, my Lad."
>
> 1699 **Dunton's conversation in Ireland**, **Life & Errors (1818)**:- "It was pretty to see the Squire choused out of so fair an estate with so little ready rhino."

Comment: The OED also gives this: *Forms:  16 ryno, 16–17 rino, 16 18– rhino. Etymology: Origin uncertain. The collocation with rhinocerical adj. in quot. a1628 suggests that the word may show a shortening of rhinoceros n. (perhaps with allusion to the value of rhinoceros horn), although this could equally reflect after-the-fact rationalization of a word of different origin, or even punning.  Compare later rhino n.2*

Answer (score 4):

*Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable* suggests 'one plausible origin' as powdered rhino horn brought back from the East, commanding a high price for its reputed properties.  Brewer's not good on definitive answers, but unbeatable for plausibility.

Comment: I also feel compelled to mention that I've only ever heard this from Brian and P G Wodehouse; but then, each of them has better English than the *Daily Mail*, let alone the *New York Times*.

Answer (score 4):

Two separate sources (although [this one](http://www.rhinosinfo.com/etymology.html#.UpYZJ8RdXzI) may well be quoting [this one](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rhino&allowed_in_frame=0)) say that "rhino" as a shortening of "rhinoceros" to mean the animal was not known until 1884.  If this is true, it seems unlikely to me that "rhino" meaning money/cash would be shortened from "rhinoceros" in the 17th century.

Coming up with other plausible suggestions is nigh on impossible though - perhaps the nose connection ("rhinos" = nose in Greek) might be a link to xiàng shù, the ancient Chinese art of physiognomy, in which one's nose shape is said to "[indicate your money situation](http://www.serenapowers.com/facereading.html)".  Pretty tenuous, I admit, but possible?

Another fairly tenuous suggestion might be a link to the Middle English word "rinen", as defined in the first etymology [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rine): *“to touch, lay hold of, reach, seize, strike, have connection with, contact”*

To be honest, I'm not convinced by either of these, but they're better than Ryan O'Neal  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The expression is very old. in Washinton Irving's "The Devil & Tom Walker", a character says "When will you want the rhino" when referring to some buried treasure. Clearly it was a common enough expression at the time, because Irving makes no effort to explain it to his readers. So, I think we can rule out Ryan O'Neil as the source.

Answer (score 1):

Rhino horn.......Corn!!    Corn is slang for money

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that the term may derive from gold brought from the Rhine. An old term for gold is Or an so this may have been termed "Rhein Or" ? This could have been around since Roman times?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. You need not be quite so polite here; answers should be answers, not framed as questions (though I understand your intent). Also, while everyone guesses at some time or another, supportable answers carry more weight. If you can link to a source to support your answer, this would be a much more valuable answer. Again, welcome.

Comment: I've never come across this term before to my knowledge but I notice that a lot of the comments and answers have Irish origins. Swift was Irish, the 1699 Dunton's reference is Irish and so on. I notice that the Gaelic for gold is **ór** and think that this might strengthen your suggestion. Try saying 'Rhine ór' in a Dublin accent.

Answer (score -1):

The first time I heard the expression was in the definition of a rhinoceros - the richest animal in the world - from rhino, meaning money and sore arse meaning piles; hence piles of money! I don't know if that helps much though.

Answer (score -2):

I was once told that it is neither form of Rhino but rather Ryan O as in the actor Ryan O'Neil who played a character who conned people out of money in the film "Paper Moon"

When people refer to Ryan O it is generally in the context of unlawfully obtained cash.

This is probably nonsense but it is interesting.

Comment: OED has a citation from 1688 which links it to rhinoceros (see Shyam's answer), and an earlier quotation from 1628. Even Ryan O'Neil isn't that old.